# Read the monitor's power status in .net

Tags: c#, .net, monitor

I'm want to develop a .net application which can read the power status (on/off) of the monitor. I tried out with DDC, but DDC doesn't supported by most of the monitors. Is there any other way to get the power status of the monitor using c#?

Answer (score 0):

you can try below piece of code :-

```
 var devices = new MSVidCtlLib.MSVidOutputDevices();

        Console.WriteLine("Found {0} devices", devices.Count);

        foreach (MSVidCtlLib.IMSVidOutputDevice dev in devices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} - {2}", dev.Name, dev.Status, dev.Power);
        }
```

More information :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd694527(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm getting a reference issue in MSVidCtlLib. Could you please instruct me how I can fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting the result as Found 0 devices. I just added your code inside the Main() and run. Is there any thing else I need to do in order to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with WMI class `WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394535(v=vs.85).aspx

From that page -
ActiveData type: booleanAccess type: Read-only

Indicates the active monitor.

Comment: As much as it is possible for me to search the net for how to use WMI classes from .Net, it is possible for you too.. I understand that initially the question can be hard to get answered, despite some searching... but now that you know where to look, I'd recommend go look.. Sorry, I don't mean to be rude or unhelpful.. StackOverflow has good rule for good reason that all questions should be accompanied with proof of research. Feel free to post another question, with your research, if you still cannot find how to use WMI classes from .Net, but I am sure it will not come to that.